# Fluent NHibernate + Lucene Search (NHibernate.Search)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, lucene, nhibernate.search, event-listener

I'm using Fluent NHibernate and I would like to implement NHibernate.Search with Lucene but I can't find any examples on how to do that with Fluent NHibernate. It appears there are two steps. (According to [Castle](http://using.castleproject.org/display/AR/Using+NHibernate.Search+with+ActiveRecord))

1. Set the Hibernate properties in the configuration:

   - hibernate.search.default.directory_provider
   - hibernate.search.default.indexBase
   - hibernate.search.analyzer
2. Initializing the Event Listeners to index persisted objcts

   - configuration.SetListener(ListenerType.PostUpdate, new FullTextIndexEventListener());
   - configuration.SetListener(ListenerType.PostInsert, new FullTextIndexEventListener());
   - configuration.SetListener(ListenerType.PostDelete, new FullTextIndexEventListener());

I figured out how to add properties to the Fluent NHibernate Source Configuration, but **I cannot find where the Event Listeners are setup.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the [Fluent Configuration](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/FluentConfiguration) API, then you just need to use the `ExposeConfiguration` method to get at the NHibernate Configuration instance.

```
Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(...)
  .Mappings(...)
  .ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
  {
    cfg.SetListener(...);
    cfg.SetListener(...);
  })
  .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: This is correct but when I tried this, I ran into other problems with the Fluent NHibernate and the NHibernate.Search assemblies using two different versions of NHibernate. So, this is correct - but it actually doesn't work. Yet. :)

Comment: @rmontgomery429 It's a solution for OSS, you should checkout from the trunk and build it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a [Fluent API for Lucene](http://github.com/trullock/Fluent-NHibernate-Search) which removes the need for attributes and integrated nicely with FNH

Its still very pre-alpha, contributions welcome!