# Lucene.Net in ASP .Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, lucene.net

Am currently looking to implement full text search in different pages of my asp .net MVC application and was thinking to use Lucene.Net to achieve this. I was hoping if someone could guide me through best practices how to achieve this in an asp .net MVC application with fluent nhibernate for multiple datatypes.

Thanks

Comment: You should make your question more specific, best practices can cover a lot. Are you looking for architectural or implementation advice for instance. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212813/fluent-nhibernate-nhibernate-serach-lucene-net) is an similar question as well.

Comment: I was looking for architectural advice, Thanks Guvante for the link.

Comment: I have integrated Lucene.net in to an in-house MVC in the past and was very happy with the results.  The main question though would be if the content is added in real time to your site, or if its something that just needs to be indexed offline or nightly.  You can approach it as a completely external system that just indexes the site via scraping from the front end, or one that's integrated in to your content data and indexes on content change incrementally.  I wrote my own analyzer/tokenizer based on HTML Agility Pack to parse my HTML content for tokens.